# PRBLEMA CON MODAL Y SHOW

Tags: laravel, show

tengo un error de variable, el objetivo de todo esto es que quisiera un modal que muestre los permisos del rol seleccionado pero al apretar el botón me muestra el error

> Undefined variable: rolesPermissions

, me pueden ayudar para saber que estoy haciendo mal por favor, adjunto el codigo HTML del modal y de SHOW del controller (rolesController)

HTML MODAL

```html
<!--modal view-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-show-roles" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <!-- View Event-->
   <div class="modal-dialog" >                           
      <div class="modal-content admin-form">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
               <!--titulo-->
               <span>{{$listado->name}}</span>
            </h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
    
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div id="view_event_alert"></div>
            <div class="section row">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form">
                       
                                 <div class="section row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                       <label class="">Permisos: </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                       <label for="" class="field">
                                          <span>
                                             @foreach ($rolesPermissions as $permisos)
                                                <span>{{ $permisos-> descripcion}}</span>
                                             @endforeach
                                          </span>
                                       </label>
                                    </div>                       
                                 </div>
                         
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>           
         </div>         
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>  
<!--./modal view-->
```

CONTROLLER

```js
public function show($id)
    {
        $roles = Role::where('id', $id)->GET();
        $rolesPermissions->getAllPermissions();
        return view('roles.show', ['roles'=>$roles,'rolesPermissions'=>$rolesPermissions]);
    }
```

Comment: en tu controlador haces `$rolesPermissions->getAllPermissiions();`, pero no tienes declarada esa variable `$rolesPermissions`. Supongo que te referirás a  `$roles->getAllPermissions();` ?

Comment: si, por que con ese código, según la documentación de spatie me muestra los permisos de ese rol

Comment: Ok, entonces ese método `getAllPermissiions()` es de la librería que mencionas, pero eso no quita que la estás aplicando a una variable que no existe. Puedes probar aplicarla a la colección que guardsate en `$roles`, pero no conozco la librería a la que te refieres, posiblemente debas aplicarla a una instancia del modelo Role, en vez de sobre una colección